# Define from include breaking other previous includes

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to debug the includes of my project's main file. Here's my include code.

```
//Gameplay
#include "gameplay.h"

//LibNoise
#include <noise/noise.h>

//Console Window
#ifndef _WINDOWS_
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>
    #undef KEY_EVENT
    #undef MOUSE_EVENT
#endif
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//RakNet
#include "MessageIdentifiers.h"
#include "RakPeerInterface.h"
#include "BitStream.h"
#include "RakNetTypes.h"

//My Includes
#include "Island.h"
```

The problem is, gameplay.h includes a file (specifically ScriptController.h) where there's an enum that contains the words KEY_EVENT and MOUSE_EVENT which is included through some includes in windows.h (specifically wincon.h). This breaks the enum and I get errors during compilation. Note, it is actually including windows.h because _WINDOWS_ isn't defined at this point according to MSVS (so it's not like it's defined before gameplay.h or something).

I can't see why this would be a problem as gameplay.h is included before windows.h which should mean that I would get no trouble with replacement of the terms in the enum? Undefining them doesn't help either.

Where did I go wrong? Is there any way I can "debug" the preprocessor and see the output from the preprocessor that is causing this syntax error and some kind of #include chain? I want to be able to fix this myself next time if it occurs.

Here's the errors

> Error  3   error C2065: 'CALLBACK_COUNT' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\pf\downloads\gameplay-master\gameplay\src\scriptcontroller.h  1024    1   testerino2
>       Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'  c:\users\pf\downloads\gameplay- master\gameplay\src\scriptcontroller.h  769 1   testerino2
>       Error   2   error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ',' c:\users\pf\downloads\gameplay-master\gameplay\src\scriptcontroller.h   769 1   testerino2

Here's the wincon.h defines

```
#define KEY_EVENT         0x0001 // Event contains key event record
#define MOUSE_EVENT       0x0002 // Event contains mouse event record
```

Here's the offending code lines of ScriptController.h

```
762| enum ScriptCallback
763| {
764|     INITIALIZE = 0,
    ...
768|     RESIZE_EVENT,
769|     KEY_EVENT,
770|     MOUSE_EVENT,
771|     TOUCH_EVENT,
    ...
775|     GAMEPAD_EVENT,
776|     CALLBACK_COUNT,
777|     INVALID_CALLBACK = CALLBACK_COUNT
778| };

...

1024| std::vector<std::string> _callbacks[CALLBACK_COUNT];
```

Comment: `i get errors during compilation` Then post them!

Comment: Woops, i will when i get home in 30 minutes

Comment: If the enum itself is defined before `windows.h` is included, then it obviously cannot break the enum itself since `KEY_EVENT` and `MOUSE_EVENT` have not been defined yet.  However, any **usage** of the enum after `windows.h` has been included would break without your `#undef` statements, which should be handling the issue just fine. So I have to think that `windows.h` is likely being included earlier then you think, before the enum is defined. Why not just include `windows.h` first at the top, then `#undef`, then include the rest of the files as needed?

Comment: Because whereever I move the gameplay.h in the order I still get the problem. I have no idea why.

Comment: Included the errors, the code I was explaining, and the line numbers for it all. If the downvote was not for any of this please explain?

Comment: @Coburn In your `gameplay.h`, are there any header files included before including `ScriptController.h`?  If yes, then Remy Lebeau's comment would still apply.

Comment: Yes there are and I checked but there is no inclusion of windows.h in there.

Comment: Aaah, found the problem. I watched the compile more closely and realize that it actually stops upon compiling the file right after this one. That file includes RakNet which includes windows.h and after includes gameplay.h which causes the problem. I thought I was insane because all of these includes are correct and it was still giving me errors but it wasn't even here. Thanks for all the help though guys.

Comment: @Coburn Write an answer with your findings then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid clashes with `windows.h` defines, I'd recommend making your own header file that:

1. Defines any macros that affect `windows.h`, such as `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`
2. Does `#include <winsock2.h>` if used, and `#include <windows.h>`
3. Does `#undef` on any annoying macros

Then make sure every source file that might come across a Windows include, includes this header. You could perhaps use a compiler feature to inject the header into all units.